# Upgrading MathJaX from version 2.5 to 2.6

Tags: mathjax

Well basically I want to upgrade MathJax in my site from version 2.5 to version 2.6. I have installed a copy of the 2.6 version in the server and then I am trying to call MathJaX linking it to the server. However, I get an upleasant message that the server cannot see the local.js file. It does the upgrade to 2.6 but it calls it from the cdn. Also, the equations are not stable. That is, if someone clicks on them well they go up and down for a while.

The configuration looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax   
     2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML,    
     https://myserver.com/MathJax/config/local/local.js">
```

In the mean while, the old version of 2.5 is still on board the server. Should I delete this? If I switch back to 2.5 version then everything is OK.

Comment: You might want to add a live sample and explain in more detail what visual problems you're encountering ("go up and down " is rather vague).

Comment: "It does the upgrade to 2.6 but it calls it from the cdn", this is because your URL for MathJax uses `cdn.mathjax.org`.  Do you mean to use my `server.com/MathJax/MathJax.js` instead?  If the *server* is giving you an error message that the file can't be found, then have you moved your `local.js` to the new MathJax folder?

Comment: Sorry for not replying later but I was quite busy with work. Yep, I fixed the problem. There was something wrong with the code I was entering. 

@DavideCervone Yes, I had moved local.js to the new MathJaX folder.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Yeah I had seen that in the facebook and have already read the announcement at the blog. I will just make the necessary changes to call it from cloud fare !! Pity though!

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Will mathjax have a new version coming up soon?

Comment: Thanks. We're posting these so whoever reads this later doesn't get surprised.

Comment: @tolaso 2.7 has been out for a while but we're working on V3 right now.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Cool! I've been using v.2.7 and I am quite pleased with it ..